# Uso de postman para comprobar mock-server con mockoon

Tags: postman, requests, response, mock, mockserver

Muy buenas

Tengo levantado un mock-server con mockoon y al comprobarlo con postman ni siquiera me conecta, me dice que el servicio está 503 unvaliable pero le meto la url a un navegador y si que me hace el response, devolviéndome un XML según le pase unos parámetros u otros, ¿Qué le pasa al POSTMAN?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Con el programa mockoon he creado un mockserver con una respuesta que devuelve un XML (el que sea) si mediante el metodo get le haces un request a la URL en la que esta alojado el Mock-server, pues si le hago el get con el navegador funciona pero si le hago el get usando Postman no funciona, ¿porqué? No lo entiendo. Un saludo.